# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: launcher package not install for tob status is off

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

I got an APK and try to install it with adb then this occured .
I got no idea about this problem.
Can anybody show me some advices?

Comment: apk file corrupted

Comment: I got this apk by a third-party app , and the other apks I got by the same way works well . Might there be something unusual in this apk? Oh ,it's a lancher app.